# Calling a function from a library in C++

Tags: c++, function

I am new to using library's in C++, and would appreciate some help to learn. I have a `main.cpp` file and a library called `maths` with `maths.cpp` and `maths.h`

I have the following function, in my `maths.cpp` file, which I want to call from `main.cpp` :

```
void maths::Readings_to_Temperature (int temperature [5]) {
    for (int n = 0 ; n < no_readings ; n++ ){ 

        temperature[n] = ((R2*temperature[n])/Vin)-R2; 

    }
}
```

I have moved it from `main.cpp`, where it worked fine, as I want to clean up the code and make it more shareable. So how do I reference it in `main.cpp`? I have read a few tutorials, but the `led.flash(5)` style example doesn't really work, as I don't have any hardware parameters to pass to it, the only data which needs passing is the variable going into `temperature`.

My current main call is:

```
Readings_to_Temperature (readings);
```

I thought maybe:

```
maths.Readings_to_Temperature (readings);
```

or 
    maths::Readings_to_Temperature (readings);

I have the `#include <maths.h>` directive at the top of `main.cpp`

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the declaration of `maths`?

Comment: Unless you are building a library file (which gets *linked* into your application) that contains `Readings_to_Temperature`, this does not seem to really have anything to do with libraries.

Comment: Also, if `maths.h` is *your* file, you should generally use `#include "maths.h"`, since the `<...>` form is generally for system headers or third-party libraries.

Comment: If you have a C++ question, don't tag it with `c`.

Comment: I don't understand how your current call can be `Reading_to_Temperature(readings)`. Since the function is a class member, it has to be called using member syntax: `object.function()` or `pointer->function()`.

Answer (score 1):

Where R2 and Vin come from ?
Did you write a class ?

Use STL as much as you can, forget C array, use [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) or [std::array](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/).

maths.h

```
#include <vector>    

namespace maths
{
    void Readings_to_Temperature (std::vector<int>& v);
}
```

maths.cpp

```
#include "maths.h"

namespace maths
{
    void Readings_to_Temperature(std::vector<int>& v)
    {
        const size_t size = v.size();
        for (size_t i = 0; size < size ; ++i)
        {
            temperature[i] = ((R2 * temperature[i]) / Vin) - R2;
        }
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <vector>
#include "maths.h"

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(5, 0); // 5 integers set to 0
    maths::Readings_to_Temperature(v);
}
```